# Knockout Validation Breaking when Bundling with WebPack

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, webpack, knockout-validation

I am creating a Knockout web application using Knockout-Validation plugin. I would like to use WebPack for bundling.

The problem is that Knockout-Validation breaks when I use WebPack.

As a simple test case I am able to get the validation working fine without bundling: https://jsfiddle.net/3y24zvLs/

HTML:

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: name">
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

JS:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable().extend({required: true});
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I'm also able to use it fine as a registered Knockout component: http://jsfiddle.net/3y24zvLs/2/

HTML:

```
<name-component></name-component>
```

JS:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable().extend({required: true});
};

ko.components.register('name-component', {
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    template: '<label>Name</label>\
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: name">\
                <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>'
});

ko.applyBindings();
```

However, when I try to use bundling the validation breaks:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="Built/main.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <name-component></name-component>
</body>
```

main.js

```
var ko = require('../node_modules/knockout/build/output/knockout-latest');
var $ = require('jquery');
require('./ViewModel');

$(function(){
  ko.applyBindings();
})
```

ViewModel.js

```
"use strict";

var ko = require('../node_modules/knockout/build/output/knockout-latest');
var kv = require('../node_modules/knockout.validation/dist/knockout.validation');

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable().extend({required: true});
};

ko.components.register('name-component', {
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    template: '<label>Name</label>\
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: name">\
                <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>'
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require('path');


module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'App'),
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'Built'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader'},
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader'}
    ]
  }
};
```

Does anyone have any idea why the validation is breaking? Does Knockout-Validation not play nice with WebPack? Maybe I should try switching to using Gulp or Grunt to bundle the components and use RequireJS instead of WebPack/CommonJS? Although I'm not entirely sure how simple that switch will be...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about taking down this question because I just solved it, but I wasted some time this morning trying to get this to work, so if I'll leave this up here to hopefully prevent other people from wasting time.

I moved the jQuery, Knockout and Knockout-Validation to the global scope and removed some redefine problems I had.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.js"></script>
    <script src="Built/main.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <name-component></name-component>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
/*
  Knockout and jQuery were moved to the global scope. Knockout exports as 
  'ko' so there is no need to redefine it here.
*/

//var ko = require('../node_modules/knockout/build/output/knockout-latest');
//var $ = require('jquery');
require('./ViewModel');

$(function(){
  ko.applyBindings();
})
```

And for completeness here are the other files:

**ViewModel.js**

```
"use strict";

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable().extend({required: true});
};

ko.components.register('name-component', {
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    template: '<label>Name</label>\
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: name">\
                <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>'
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require('path');


module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'App'),
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'Built'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader'},
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader'}
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't know how you do it with WebPack, but ko.validation requires ko to be defined as a global variable. If you load ko with CommonJS you're probably avoiding it to define the global ko. In `require.js` you need to use a shim for thsi to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072784/how-to-load-knockout-validation-with-knockout-in-requirejs This solution is, mmmm, let's call it "not good", not so say something more abrupt ;) This problem is also usual with something like jQuery plugins which also depend on $/jQuery defined in the global scope.

Comment: I had it working with RequireJS but I wanted to use WebPack because it's fairly simple and I can use it to transpile es6 with babel. Would you recommend a different tool (e.g., gulp, browserfy, etc.?) As far as my current solution being "not good" do you mean that bringing in ko, kv, and jQuery through global script tags as not being ideal?

Comment: Yes, that was the reason for the "no good". As you say, you can use grunt or gulp. Remember that there is also a require js optimizer that also allows custom bundling. Setting up a grunt with babel transpiler and require js optimizer should take little time. Specially if you have some experience. The require optimizer will spare you the time to minify and concat. By the way, there are also Babel plugins for require js,so that the optimizer can also do that job for you. For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs-babel-plugin

Comment: In case it's not clear, if you use plugins with requirejs, like `text!` or `es6!`, requirejs optimizer will run the plugin (for example the `es6` transpiling), and include the result in the optimize(d) bundles. So you simply have to compile and optimize. Forget about minifying, bundling, and so on yourself.